# Conference Registration Fees are so high, is it normal?

Tags: conference, ieee

My colleague research paper got accepted at a conference named (International Conference On Trust, Security And Privacy In Computing And Communications http://www.cloud-conf.net/trustcom18/). They claim that the conference is A-Ranked according to core2018 when you check it as IEEE Trustcom. Is it correct that this conference is A-Ranked conference (http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/790/)? is it really the same conference or they are taking advantage of this misunderstanding?

Also, I got shocked when I noticed that the student registration fee is $1095.00 for regular research papers. The full accepted paper has only limited 6 pages in length to be included in the final proceedings. My research paper is 12 pages. 
The program committee wants to charge me $150.00 for each extra page. This in total will be around $2000.00 just as registration fees.

Is it normal too?

Comment: It sounds like SPIE. That is to say, it's an important conference where everyone in the field is expected to go, and it's outrageously expensive.

Answer (score 7):

> is it really the same conference or they are taking advantage of this misunderstanding?

I am not in the field of security, but yes, this appears to be the right conference. Your advisor should be able to clarify with certainty.

> Also, I got shocked when I noticed that the student registration fee is $1095.00 for regular research papers.

It's quite expensive even in comparison to other conferences, but it's the same ballpark as other IEEE conferences, so (unfortunately) this seems to be the direction we are heading to. However, I cannot help but wonder if you did not check the prices prior to submission?

> The full accepted paper has only limited 6 pages in length to be included in the final proceedings. My research paper is 12 pages. The program committee wants to charge me $150.00 for each extra page.

Yeah, that sounds pretty terrible. I would be interested in why the community does not push back more on what certainly appears to be a shady "hidden cost" model that is unworthy of a good academic conference. I know that some other conferences allow one or two extra pages for additional charge (which, frankly, is also ridiculous in times of Web-based proceedings), but limiting the "free" number of pages to 6 (clearly too little for most scientific contributions) and then letting the author pay for the same number of extra pages to get to what is the normal length of full conference papers (10-12 pages) seems completely fishy.

I would complain as well, but realistically there really is not much that you as a student can do (aside from withdrawing, and you probably don't want to do that).

---

To give you some more context, it is unfortunately true that academic conference *are* very expensive and that they have only been getting more expensive over recent years. To me it subjectively appears to be the case that IEEE conferences are particularly prone to overcharging, but this may just be my impression. Some communities have started to push back on this, though. For instance, one of the main promises of a current candidate running for the position of SIGSOFT chair is to reduce the price tag for SIGSOFT sponsored events.

Comment: "it is unfortunately true that academic conference are very expensive" this is not true in every field or for every conference series. In chemistry many conferences charge something like $ 400-500 and got huge discount for students. And for example a Gordon Research Conference comes down to maybe $1400 including housing and food.

Comment: ''However, I cannot help but wonder if you did not check the prices prior to submission?'' They made all of that information available after the acceptance notification...

Comment: Many conferences do not have the fees up on the same page as t(e call for papers. You’d need to dig up the archives to figure out the costs.

Comment: @aeismail I tried to edit the url to minus 1 for 18 to make 17 in order to check archive 2017 but did not work. Searched directly and I found it. wonder why Conference keep changing the name of their websites? makes a lot of confusion...

Comment: That’s generally a sign that the local organizing committee is responsible for producing and hosting the website.